# How can I render matching text with Pango on two computers?

Tags: dpi, cairo, freetype, pango

We have tests that check how code build on Gtk with Pango and Cairo renders shapes and text.

I can't get font rendering to match between different developers computers and CI.

The font seems to render 1 or 2 pixels higher or lower.

Hinting, and DPI may be setup different between these machines, can I set some environment variables to ensure fonts render at the same size and with the same hinting ?

Comment: A quick look at `git grep getenv` in cairo does not find anything interesting. What cairo versions are involved? Cairo recently gained support for subpixel positioning of glyphs. Before that, it rounded glyph positions to integer positions, I think. Besides that, no good ideas right now.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this, I'll need to get our examples converted into pycairo and retest, then maybe come to the mailing list (currently, they are in shoebot, which has a few layers before calling pycairo).